# splitting a string into an array of 3 character from behind

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

I'm looking to split a numeric random string like "12345567" into the array  ["12","345","567"] as simply as possible. basically changing a number into a human readable number array with splits at thousands,million, billions, etc..

my previous solution cuts it from the front rather than back

```
"'12345567".to_s.scan(/.{1,#{3}}/)
#> ["123","455","67"]
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `"12345567".reverse.scan(/.{1,3}/).reverse.map(&:reverse)` - works, but ugly as hell, Avinash's solution is a way to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on Rails, you can use the [number_with_delimiter](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_with_delimiter) helper. In plain Ruby, you can include it.

```
require 'action_view'
require 'action_view/helpers'
include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper

number_with_delimiter("12345567", :delimiter => ',')
# => "12,345,567"
```

You can do a split on the comma, to get an `Array`

Comment: Rails is great. But I would expect "the answer" to the question to be more of a *crafted* solution. This canned answer is worth, definitely---do not reinvent the wheel---but we'd like to create brain connections, not just black-box dumps. I believe Avinash's answer was timely and well detailed---worth reading if not accepting.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the below.

```
> "12345567".scan(/\d+?(?=(?:\d{3})*$)/)
=> ["12", "345", "567"]
```

`\d+?` will do a non-greedy match of one or more digits which must be followed by exactly three digits, zero or more times and further followed by the end of a line.

- `\d+?` will do a [non-greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) match of one or more digits.
- `(?=..)` called [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) which asserts that the match must be followed by,

  1. `(?:\d{3})*` exactly three digits of zero or more times. So this would match an empty string or 111 or 111111 like multiples of 3.
  2. `$` End of the line anchor which matches the boundary which exists at the last.

**OR**

```
> "12345567".scan(/.{1,3}(?=(?:.{3})*$)/)
=> ["12", "345", "567"]
```

Comment: Thanks, is there anyway to make it look like less wizerdry?

Comment: ruby is supposed to be the "easy" to read language frankly " (/\d+?(?=(?:\d{3})*$)/) " looks much like sorcery. I know it's regex, but is learning them by heart required to code in ruby?

Comment: did you wanna a explanation?

Comment: lonewarrior, it only looks "wizardry" because you are not familiar with the language.  When you learn more about regular expressions (which you must do), you'll find that this one is relatively straightforward.

Comment: Very nice, Avinash. Where I said "relatively straightforward" above, I was referring to one understanding how your regex works.

Comment: Note that `\d+?` could be replaced with `\d{1,3}` or (if the string might be empty)  `\d{,3}`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one non-regex solution:

```
s = "12345567"

sz = s.size
n_first = sz % 3
((n_first>0) ? [s[0,n_first]] : []) + (n_first...sz).step(3).map { |i| s[i,3] }
  #=> ["12", "345", "567"]
```

Another:

```
s.reverse.chars.each_slice(3).map { |a| a.join.reverse }.reverse
  #=> ["12", "345", "567"]
```

Answer (score 1):

A recursive approach:

```
def split(str)
  str.size <= 3 ? [str] : (split(str[0..-4]) + [str[-3..-1]])
end
```

Hardly readable, though. Perhaps a more explicit code layout:

```
def split(str)
  if str.size <= 3 then
    [str]  # Too short, keep it all.
  else
    split(str[0..-4]) + [str[-3..-1]] # Append the last 3, and recurse on the head.
  end
end
```

Disclaimer: No test whatsoever on performance (or attempt to go for a clear tail recursion)! Just an alternative to explore.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what you want, but maybe:

```
"12345567".scan(/^..|.{1,3}/)
=> ["12", "345", "567"]
```